# jquery help with next() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide, dom-manipulation

I have some HTML markup that looks like this,

```
        </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><img src="/media/icons/view.jpg" alt="Views"/> 210</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><img src="/media/icons/like.jpg" alt="Likes"/> 45</a></li>
                <li class="jobs"><a href="">52 New Jobs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <ul class="job_listings">
            <li><a href="">Outbound Telesales Assistant &gt;</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Business Development Manager &gt;</a></li>
        </ul
    </li>
```

The `.job_listings` is hidden on dom ready and needs to be show when `li.jobs a` is clicked, I have tried this with the following, jQuery:

```
$('#jobwall .jobs a').click(function(){
                $(this).next('.job_listing').show();
                return false;
            });
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? What did you hope would happen, and why?

Answer (score 5):

You should get the next element of nav element and not the anchor, and also you are missing s in the .job_listing selector.

Try this:

```
$('#jobwall .jobs a').click(function(){                 
    $(this).closest("nav").next('.job_listings').show();                 
    return false;             
});
```

Comment: There's no need to hard-code the NAV and .job_listings elements as siblings. My solution is more flexible.

Comment: @Sime: If there is only once container which would hold the job listing sthen we don't need any navigation it could be as simple as $("#jobListings").show(). But if it is in a repeating list then we can't use id since id should unique across HML elements.

Comment: In that case the common  ancestor can be selected by class - that is not the issue. My point is that jumping to the common ancestor and then jumping back to the other element is more flexible (= better) than hard-coding the exact relationship between various related elements (in this case, the NAV and .job_listings elements).

Comment: @Sime: Agreed on jumping to common ancestor and then jumping back (in which case you can't use ID selector if it is a repeating set of elements).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(this).closest('#commonContainer').find('.job_listings').show();
```